# Material UI v5 Different Primary Color Based on Mode (Light/Dark)

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I noticed a different primary.main color between light and dark mode. I was wondering if I can replicate that with one createTheme call.

**Using the default theme with:**

```
createTheme({
        palette: {
            mode: themeMode,
        },
});
```

**On light mode**: the `primary.main` color is **#1976d2**, as described on https://next.material-ui.com/customization/default-theme/#main-content.

**On dark mode**: the `primary.main` color is **#90caf9**. This is actually what I would like as it fits better in the dark background.

**Using the default theme with explicit but the same primary.main color**

```
createTheme({
        palette: {
            mode: themeMode,
            primary: {
                main: "#1976d2",
            },
        },
});
```

**On light mode**: the `primary.main` color is **#1976d2**.

**On dark mode**: the `primary.main` color is **#1976d2**.

Now, I'm wondering if the default theme's 'dynamic' `primary.main` color is something I can achieve with a different color in with one `createTheme`. If not, what's the best approach assuming your theme outside `palette` is to be complicated in the future?

Answer (score 0):

In my case `createTheme` is getting called again for both the light and dark mode.  I see that `themeMode` changes, so I use that to adjust the palette.

```js
createTheme({
  palette: {
    mode: themeMode,
    primary: {
      main: themeMode === "light" ? "#1976d2" : "#90caf9",
    },
  },
});
```